How to change a map and his subtypes in Dart?
I want to change a map changing also her subtypes that can be list or also map.
Here my map:
var mydata = {
  "data": {
    "user1": {
      "notes": ["a", "b", "c"],
      "todos": ["a", "b", "c"],
      "categories": ["a", "b", "c"],
    }
  }
};

and here how it should be:
var mydata = {
  "\"data\"": {
    "\"user1\"": {
      "\"notes\"": ["\"a\"", "\"b\"", "\"c\""],
      "\"todos\"": ["\"a\"", "\"b\"", "\"c\""],
      "\"categories\"": ["\"a\"", "\"b\"", "\"c\""]
    }
  }
}

In each String, I add a “ at the start and a “ at the end.
Thanks in advice.

Can you provide details and examples of what problem you're encountering?  It's not clear what you're asking.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Because I use JSON with Mysql, and Mysql removes the ". So the json can't decode it. And if I have ""data", I add a second ".
